# Combining two columns from separate tables into one in SQL Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I'm trying to run a query that requires me to join two separate tables together, but I'm required to consolidate some information into a single column, and tag which table it came from.

Like this...

```
    table_1            table_2
    teacher_name       student_name
    Steve              Jimmy
    George             Craig

    Output:

    NAME:       Title:
    Steve       Teacher
    George      Teacher
    Jimmy       Student
    Craig       Student
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
    SELECT x.first_name, x.last_name, y.first_name, y.last_name, x.city, y.city
    FROM (SELECT i.first_name, i.last_name, z.city, z.zip
    FROM instructor i JOIN
    zipcode z
    ON z.zip = i.zip
    WHERE z.zip = 10025) x

        LEFT OUTER JOIN

            (SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, z.city, z.zip
            FROM student s JOIN zipcode z
            ON s.zip = z.zip
            WHERE z.zip = 10025) y
            ON y.zip = x.zip
```

Essentially, all that I need to do is to combine the first and last names from the x and y query into a single column, as well as the city from both, and then create a column that identifies whether or not the person came from the instructor table (x) or the student table (y)

Update:

So I ended up ditching the sub-queries and the outer joins, I got the query working... here's the code I ended up with. Thank you so much!

```
    SELECT i.first_name AS first_name, i.last_name AS last_name, 'Teacher' AS role
    FROM instructor i JOIN zipcode z
    ON i.zip = z.zip
    WHERE z.zip = 10025

    UNION ALL

    SELECT s.first_name AS first_name, s.last_name AS last_name, 'Student' AS role
    FROM  student s JOIN zipcode z
    ON s.zip = z.zip
    WHERE z.zip = 10025
    ORDER BY role, last_name, first_name;
```

Comment: can you show us some sample data and expected output? Right now only First Name, not Last Name or city. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT teacher_name + teacher_last as Name, city, 'Teacher' as source
FROM TeacherTable       
UNION ALL
SELECT student_name + student_last as Name, city, 'Student' as source
FROM StudentTable
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, and simplified the crap out of my code. Sorry if my question was poorly worded. That did give me a good place to start off with.

Comment: @B1azingPh03nix In your update solution you dont need `JOIN zipcode`, instead of `z.zip` just use `WHERE  i.zip = 10025`